# Can't create multiple pushpins on map

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I've been struggling for a while to display multiple pushpins on a map in Windows Phone 8 application using the Map Control (not a Bing map). Here's my code:

```
void webClient_PlacesNearbyDownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
   try
   {
       if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Result))
          {
             MapLayer NearbyPlacesLayer = new MapLayer();
             Image Pushpin = new Image();
             Pushpin.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Assets/Icons/pushpin.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
             Pushpin.Width = 26;
             Pushpin.Height = 26;
             Pushpin.Opacity = 100;

             RootObject query = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(e.Result);
             List<Item> places = query.results.items.ToList();

             foreach (Item item in places)
             {
                 Debug.WriteLine(item.position[0]);
                 Debug.WriteLine(item.position[1]);

                 MapOverlay MyOverlay = new MapOverlay();

                 MyOverlay.Content = Pushpin;
                 MyOverlay.GeoCoordinate = new GeoCoordinate(item.position[0], item.position[1]);
                 MyOverlay.PositionOrigin = new Point(0.0, 1.0);
                 NearbyPlacesLayer.Add(MyOverlay);
             }
             Map.Layers.Add(NearbyPlacesLayer);
           }        
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
           MessageBox.Show("Oops");
      }
      finally
      {
           ProgressBar.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
      }
}
```

However this code crashes the application and says:

> The program '[1904] TaskHost.exe' has exited with code -1
>   (0xffffffff).

I can't figure out what seems to be the problem. Need your advice.

P.S. The two lines of `Debug.WriteLine` write correct coordinates for each item in my list.

Comment: Ok. Apparently I need to create a unique name to each new `Image` and  `MapOverlay`